# SQL Server developer Edition License and CAL

Tags: sql-server, licensing

I have to test my product with SQL Server database. Based on the search, I know I have to get hold of Developer Edition. I need to know whether for my team of 10 to access the database for  testing needs 10 CALs or 10 developer licenses?

I searched enough in the net but couldn't find a straight answer.

My test setup will be like, SQL Server Developer Edition will be installed in a Test QA machine and my team will connect to that machine to test our product with.

Thanks,
ramanr

Comment: iirc, it's OK as long as it's not for commercial use - only development.

Comment: Maybe `serverfault.com` is in a better position to respond to this type of questions.

Comment: I disagree with the serverfault thing on this one; this is dev specific.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server 2008 Developer, [Microsoft's licensing page](http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/userights/ProductPage.aspx?pid=325) states:

> You must acquire a license for each user you permit to access or use the
>   software. You may install any number of copies on any number of devices for
>   access and use by one user to design, develop, test and demonstrate
>   programs. Only licensed users may access the software.

They also state:

> *Demonstration*. In addition to the licensed user, any person that has
>   access to your internal network may install and use copies of the software
>   to demonstrate use of your programs with the software.

ISTR SQL Server 2005 is similar: i.e., one copy per developer.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Chris J's answer, the licensing also provides:

**II) Additional Licensing Requirements and/or Use Rights.**

User Testing. Your end users may access the software to perform acceptance tests on your programs.

Comment: Don't know about SQL Server 2008 R2 but the 2012 Developer Edition licence terms state these additional rights for user testing are for MSDN subscriptions only: http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/ProductPage.aspx?pid=410

Answer (score 1):

**Microsoft** answers:
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/developer.aspx